# When will Ubuntu migrate to GTK+ 3.0?

Tags: gtk

I just got known that GTK+ 3.0.0 [has been released](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-February/msg00031.html).

- Will Ubuntu 10.10/11.04 come with runtime libraries for GTK+ 3.0? 
  Are these installed by default?
- Will Ubuntu have development libraries and header files for compilation of GTK+ 3.0 programs?
- When will Ubuntu (as whole) move to GTK 3?

I'm mostly concerned about moving [audio-recorder app](https://launchpad.net/audio-recorder) from GTK+ 2.x to 3.0.

References:

- [Migrating from GTK+ 2 to GTK+ 3](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk3/3.0/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html) guide
- GTK+ 3 [Reference Manual](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk3/3.0/index.html):

Comment: how can i know abt the gtk version which ubuntu does have during installation...and do nautilus use gtk..???  

in what IDE nautilus is written..?

Answer (score 4):

GTK+ 3.0 will be available for 11.04, but not included by default and none of the default applications will be built with gtk3.  This will give application developers time to port to gtk3, theme engines and themes to be updated, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Ubuntu 10.10 will NOT come with GTK+ 3.0 runtime libraries nor header files. Maybe they will be obtainable from some external resources, like PPA's.
- Ubuntu 11.04 SHOULD (as whole) move to GTK+ 3.0 (at least: most applications).
- Ubuntu 11.04 WILL have runtime libraries for GTK+3.0. They should be installed by default.
- Ubuntu 11.04 WILL have development libraries and header files for GTK+ 3.0, but they will NOT be installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
As of Ubuntu 11.10, Unity uses GTK 3 and gnome-shell has been added to the repo and can be installed alongside Unity and other window managers.

Ubuntu 11.10 will have Gnome 3 support built-in:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/gnome-shell-is-finally-available-in.html

I believe that they are working on porting Unity to GTK 3 as well. (NOT Gnome 3)

Comment: What do you mean by "NOT Gnome 3"? 11.10 does use Gnome 3.

Comment: @jo-erlend it will have Gnome 3 as an option, but Unity will not be Gnome 3. there are two technologies: GTK 3, which is the actual UI framework, then Gnome 3, which is all the applications and the new gnome-shell window manager. I was just trying to make it clear that Unity != Gnome 3

Answer (score 0):

It will be available in Natty (11.04):
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0

Apart from that fact I'm not sure if it is a good idea to rush to a recent version of a library in your program. That makes installation on 'older'linux distributions harder.